# beam typeshints for GroupByKey

Tags: python, apache-beam

Hit problems using GroupByKey and I believe tracked it back to a type problem. I've looked at this for a while and followed a few stack traces, but its not clear to me why the following is wrong

```
@beam.typehints.with_output_types(beam.typehints.Tuple[long, float])
class MultiMap(beam.DoFn):
   def process(self, element):
      items = element.split(',')
      print items
      r =  (long(items[0]), float(items[10]))
      print r
      return r


   pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
   pcoll = pipeline | 'start' >> beam.Create(['14172425165068797305,3,0,3,0.07,0.36,1,4,4,3705.00765154,0.235002550513','2746375035268210383,3,0,3,0.07,0.36,2,5,5,3789.1391067,0.263046368899','16101396351712676789,3,0,3,0.07,0.37,1,4,3,3639.26112282,0.213087040939'])
   multi = pcoll | "Multimap" >> beam.ParDo(MultiMap()).with_output_types(beam.typehints.Tuple[long, float])
```

Using DirectRunner, I get the following exception.

```
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 227, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ReadOperation.start   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 228, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ReadOperation.start   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 229, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ReadOperation.start   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 238, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ReadOperation.start   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 159, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 392, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process   File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 393, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process   File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 488, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive   File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 496, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process   File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 537, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value TypeError: 'long' object is not subscriptable [while running 'Multimap']
```

Need to figure out why this is failing to pass the output of the ParDo into GroupByKey.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution although it is not clear to my why the change is required. All I did was change the 'return' in the process method to a 'yield' and it works. Seems like with the return the full pcollection wasn't being created. Also when removing the type hints in the example yield or return works. With the type hints, however, only yield works.

This is pretty surprising behavior and rather hard to debug. The [beam docs on ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) seem to use use return and yield interchangeable without explaining when to use them.

Is this a bug or just missing docs?